# mysqlsh: How to import a dump file

Tags: mysql, command-line, mariadb

Usually I have a local installation of a MariaDB and when I import an sql-dump I use the following command:

```
C:\Program\MariaDB\bin\mysql testdb < C:\Downloads\dump.sql -u mariadbadmin -p -h localhost
```

where `testdb` ist the database I want to be loaded with the content of `dump.sql`. Now, I have a remote instance of MariaDB and the administrator installed on my local computer (Windows 10) the client [mysqlsh](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-features.html).

I did not succeed to import the dump file. For example I tried:

```
mysqlsh -h vm-remote -u mariadbadmin -p --mysql testdb <C:\Downloads\dump.sql
```

which gives me:

```
Conflicting options: provided host differs frm host in the URI
```

Can someone show me how is the correct syntax to import a dump file using `mysqlsh`?

Comment: mysqlsh is a MySQL only utility, its use with MariaDB is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution

```
mysqlsh -h vm-remote -u mariadbadmin -p --sql
MySQL  vm-remote:3306  SQL > use testdb;
MySQL  vm-remote:3306  test0  SQL > \.  C:\Downloads\dump.sql
```

There is an output on the shell for the inserts but it stops after few inserts. So, if ther are millions of inserts not every will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

enter into MariaDB as root user

```
mysqldump --databases testdb > dump.sql
```

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I wanted to import tables from an existing dump using mysqlsh-client.